# how to delete rows from excel who has red background color using python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

read_file.style.apply(lambda x: [ 'background-color:%s' % 'red' if x < y else 'background-color :%s' % 'green' for x in read_file.language], axis=0 ,inplace=True)
print("done")
read_file.to_excel('coloured.xlsx',engine='openpyxl', index=False)

Comment: i write this for adding color in rows but this also not working btw this is for just testing i have an different excel sheet which has so mny rows and i have to delete which has red bg color so please tell me how can i remove such rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
excel_file = 'color.xlsx' 
wb = load_workbook(excel_file, data_only = True)
sh = wb['Sheet1']

out = []
for row in sh:
    if row[0].fill.start_color.index == '00000000':
        out.append([row[i].value for i in range(len(row))])
        
pd.DataFrame(out).to_excel('no_red.xlsx')
```

color.xlsx:

[image]

no_red.xlsx:

[image]

More than one column input:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: what if the user chooses an *approximately* red color? are you sure you use the pure red color when you manually set the background in excel?

Comment: i tried ur code so many time sit only works for single column . what to do if there are 4-5 columns and if in 1 column there is red then it will remove whole row

Comment: Edited the code for that situation.

Comment: yeah now its working fine thank you

Comment: but can we do something without dataframe? as it add a one more row  ie 0,1,2..

Comment: Use header=False in to_excel function.

Comment: 0,1,2... coming both sides above and on left side. i used this header = false but i am asking for left side column.

Comment: Use index = False too.

Comment: why it remove every row which has some color not only red it remove green blue yellow coloured row also

Comment: The condition is any color except white. you can change it as you want.

Comment: how can i change for only red?

Comment: It depends on your red. In my example you can use row[0].fill.start_color.index!='FFFF0000'.

Comment: hey keramat what if apart from rows i have to remove columns also like after removing red rows i have to just take 2 columns out of 3 to next file. how can we do that?
i used seperately drop() function but after using this code for removing red rows drop is not working here

Comment: Do you mean that you want to keep just two cells in each row?

Comment: now its done thank u how can i connect with u if i have doubts in future

Comment: You're welcome. Please look at my profile for more information.